# codeigniter Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::update()

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-access, odbc

I am getting this error:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined method **CI_DB_odbc_driver::update()**" when I try to run update query.

```
      $data = array(
            'userid' => 30,
            'checktime' => '29-Dec-16 6:20PM'
        );
        $this->db->update('checkinout', $data,'userid');
```

I am using access database and the query is to update  `checkinout` table

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this...

```
$id=30;
$data = array(
            'userid' => $id,
            'checktime' => '29-Dec-16 6:20PM'
        );
$this->db->where('userid',$id);
$this->db->update('checkinout', $data);
```

OR like this..

```
$this->db->update('checkinout', $data,  "userid= 30");
```

Lets see in your statement here,

```
$this->db->update('checkinout', $data,'userid');
```

`userid` is string but for updating you have to also pass the value. Or you can update using `$this->db->where($id)` then just passing data in update statement.

Comment: give some explanation about the mistake or error for clarification.